# When using ggplot, how can I replace the p-value by a string?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I need to draw boxplots for two groups, and I'd like to add the p-value to the plot, like this:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
             value = c(1:10))

ggplot(data = df,
   mapping = aes(x = group, y = value)) +
geom_boxplot() +
stat_compare_means()
```

However, instead of the super accurate p-value, I'd like to just write "p<0.05". Is is possible to do this using the label argument inside of stat_compare_means()? Or do I need to use the annotate function?

In addition, is it possible to do something like: write "p<0.05" if p<0.05, otherwise write "n.s."?

Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by setting `label="p.singif"` and setting your desired outpoints and labels via argument `symnum.args`:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

df <- data.frame(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                 value = c(1:10))

ggplot(data = df,
       mapping = aes(x = group, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", 
                     symnum.args = list(cutpoints = c(0, 0.05, 1), 
                                        symbols = c("p<0.05", "ns")))
```

[image]

Comment: Yep. Of course. You could use `label.x.npc=.5` to put the label in the middle and additionally use `hjust=.5` as by default it will be aligned to the left (hjust=0).